# Run macro when cell changes pass value

Tags: vba

I have this certain code on a worksheet event cell change. It finds certain data that I have on a Worksheet when I type an id_parameter on cell A1.

After data is found, it writes it on this worksheet.

Now I'd like to run a different macro when I change the values on column C of the data.

I'm not able to find the proper procedure. Do_something() receives the value changed in column C. I hope I explained it clearly enough.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Search_data
    End If
    'Data is written in B2:E10

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C10")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Do_something(Target.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of type missmatch. 

What kind of type should Do_something() receive?

Comment: it means that you are trying to pass a different type then it's decalred in `Do_something`  function (or Sub). how is `Sub Do_something` defined ? what value are you trying to pass with `Target.Value` ?

Comment: Post the signature of the Do_something sub i.e. Do_something(target As datatype)

Comment: If the event handler is triggered by multiple cells changing, then `Target.Value` will be an array, not a single value.  You should account for that possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted works as intended. The issue is most probably due to Search_Data and or Do_Something.

You change the cell A1 which then changes all cells from B2:E10. Including the changed C2:C10 so make sure that the change_event cannot be triggered again by this.

```
Option Explicit
Public EventsDisabled As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not EventsDisabled Then
      EventsDisabled = True
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call search_data
    End If
    'Data is written in B2:E10

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C10")) Is Nothing Then
        Call do_something(Target.Value)
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The Public variable EventsDisabled will make sure that the change event runs when a user input is given but not if a Worksheet_Change event changes the worksheet. Otherwise you will run into all sorts of weird loopings which might be infinite or at least take a long time. Your issue will most probably also be related to this. Make sure that your Do_Something sub has the right input type. You should set a few breakpoints and open the local window under:
view>local window here you can see all variables and objects and their type. You can also type:

```
debug.print typename(Target.value)
```

into the direct window and then see what type you need to type into the Do_Something signature.